# How can I make elements of a list part of a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I have a list of strings, lets say: `my_list = ['hope', 'faith', 'help']`

now I open a textfile with the name `infile` and seperate the words with 
`for line in infile:
    line_list = line.split()` 
now I want to make a regex that i can change by using for loop like this:

```
for word in line_list:
     match = re.findall(word$, line_list)
     print(match)
```

I've tried several ways to get 'word' into that regex but none seems to work
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any regex in your code

Comment: Well 'hope' or 'faith' should be a regex, even though it is a very simple one, right? And I would like each element of the list to be searched in the textfile, that's why I thought I'd take a re.findall.

Comment: Do you know what a regex is? What you have here is a list of elements to search, not a regular expression that matches your search

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regular expression. There is the method `endswith` for the standard type `str` in Python.

```
with open('path/name.ext') as infile :
    line_list = infile.readlines()

for line in line_list :
    match = [word for word in my_list if line.endswith(word)]
    print(match)
```

This would print out either the matching word or an empty list for every line in the file.

But you can do it with a regular expression if you absolutely want...

```
pattern = r'({0})$'.format('|'.join(my_list))

for line in line_list :
    match = re.findall(pattern, line)
    print(match)
```

The search pattern contains of a group with all elements from `my_list` operated with a logical `or` `|`.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is just a string which may or may not contain wildcard or special characters. So the best way to "make elements of a list part of a regex" is to 'write' the regex :

```
my_list = ['hope', 'faith', 'help']
for regex_el in my_list:
    regex = "{0:s}".format(regex_el)
    print regex
```

Of course that is over simplistic. That's just using a plain string as a regex. You could have small regular expressions to bolt into the larger regex or you could surround the element from the list with other parts of a regex :

```
regex = "^ *{0:s} ".format(regex_el)
```

Would construct a regex to find your word only if it were the first word in a string, preceded by none or more spaces and followed by a space.

Then in your code, replace the 'word' in your call to findall with the 'regex' constructed above.

You will need to replace the `line_list` in your call to findall as well as findall expects a pattern (be that a simple string or a genuine regex) and a string in which to search (that could be `word` in your loop or `line` from the loop over lines in the file.

Also note `print match` will print an empty list if no match was found. You may wish to replace that with

```
if match:
    print(match)
```

To only print words from the line which match your constructed regex.

Could I recommend you check out this website : https://regex101.com/ to experiment with regexs and the strings you're aplying them to.